# Images not loading immediately after uploading in sails.js when app is running on production environment

Tags: node.js, image, file-upload, sails.js, image-uploading

I have uploaded and stored images in /assets/images/path/to/image . All was fine in development environment. But when I run my app in production environment first got problem that Images not showing immediately after uploading. But can view the image after restart the server by sails lift.

I searched for solution and got the idea to copy the same uploaded file in /.tmp folder to Immediately access the uploaded image. So I try this solution and use following code to copy the images in .tmp folder...

```
var tempLocation = process.cwd()+ '/.tmp/public/images/custom/path/to/image';
fs.createReadStream(uploadLocation).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tempLocation));
```

But then I got error when writing in .tmp

```
    events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, open path/to/.tmp/folder;
```

I have grunt installed both globally and locally. So don't think it is a problem. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Look at this. This solved it for me http://nickholdren.com/2014/11/20/uploading-files-in-sails-js/